# Zend Framework 2 - Internal server error in module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, internal-server-error

I just created a module with a submodule like `Backend\Entity1`. I checked every path and namespace, they all seem to be ok.

I took out codeblocks one by one but stil I just get via Firebug a

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Any ideas what I can do to find the error?

I just don't know what might be wrong. Honestly, why does the framework explain itself what is happening? Its just fishing in the dark now...

BTW: The error.log doesn't show something either...

**Edit:**

I'm guessing that this error is raised because my app can't find the `phtml` files. Maybe I'm wrong but usually when I get this kind of silly error it has something to do with missing files...

My config code looks like this:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'entity' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

My namespace is `MasterData\Entity` and my add/edit/delete/index.phtml lie under `view\masterdata\entity`.

Any ideas how I can tell the `TemplatePathStack` how to look in this dir for my files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your want your sub module to be accessed create proper route in the parent module to make a way to access your sub module.

I IMHO if you need to create sub modules, create as module and place the modules under modules folder of your application, if you have components or third party modules place it under vendor folder.

This would be easier to manage at later stages an your url will also be much simpler

Comment: so you say that if i have 10 master data entities i should create 10 modules...one for each class?

Comment: create all 10 entities in one module(ex. public-entity-module) and expose the entities through module service config either through service factory or invokable, I usually create an api module that include all utility classes and base classes and create each module for components like users(which expose all classes for managing user like registration, login, etc,) so that I can easily port this api or components in other projects

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created the new model in another way but I had the same error when I tried to see the result in the explorer. The problem (in my situation) was the access to files from the explorer, It resolves by changing files's permissions in linux's terminal.